# HTML, MySQL and PHP -> no text boxes

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox, textbox

Hello and a good evening to you all,

I´ve been a long time lurker of this site, but for the first time I could not find an answer to my question.

I have to create a small administration interface for my IT classes. I have everything up and running, and I created a database. I am trying to work out how I can create different queries when a checkbox is checked. When I remove all the PHP code, the webpage shows me all the text boxes but when adding the PHP code, all the boxes seem to disappear. I can´t work out how this is possible.

Here is my code (the names of the items are in Dutch but I don´t think that will be of any problem since the idea is the same...)

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Mutatie toevoegen</h1>

<?php
include 'config.php';

if(isset($_POST['verzenden']))
{
$bedrag=$_POST['bedrag'];
$voornaam=$_POST['voornaam'];
$achternaam=$_POST['achternaam'];
$contant=$_POST['contant'];
$datum=$_POST['datum'];
$omschrijving=$_POST['omschrijving'];
$uitgave=$_POST['uitgave'];
$bonnetje=$_POST['bonnetje'];

if($uitgave == 'uitgave')
{
   //Het is een uitgave
  if($contant == 'contant')
  {
      //het is contant, er moet voor een bonnetje bij
      $bonnetje=$_GET['uitgave_id']+1;
      $query="insert into uitgaven(bedrag, voornaam, achternaam, contant, datum, omschrijving, bonnetje)
      values('$bedrag', '$voornaam', '$achternaam', '$contant', '$datum', '$omschrijving', '$bonnetje')";
  }
  else
  {
      //het is niet contant, er hoeft niets bij
      $query="insert into uitgaven(bedrag, voornaam, achternaam, contant, datum, omschrijving)
      values('$bedrag', '$voornaam', '$achternaam', '$contant', '$datum', '$omschrijving')";
  }
}
else
{
  //Het is een inkomst
  if($contant == 'contant')
  {
      //het is contant, er moet voor een bonnetje bij
      $bonnetje=$_GET['inkomsten_id']+1;
      $query="insert into inkomsten(bedrag, voornaam, achternaam, contant, datum, omschrijving, bonnetje)
      values('$bedrag', '$voornaam', '$achternaam', '$contant', '$datum', '$omschrijving', '$bonnetje')";
  }
  else
  {
      //het is niet contant, er hoeft niets bij
      $query="insert into inkomsten(bedrag, voornaam, achternaam, contant, datum, omschrijving)
      values('$bedrag', '$voornaam', '$achternaam', '$contant', '$datum', '$omschrijving')"//     }
}




if(mysql_query($query))
{
        echo '<p>De nieuwe gegevens zijn toegevoegd.<br>';
        echo 'Controleer dit op <a href=studenten.php>studenten.php</a></p>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<p>Er is iets fout gegaan!</p>';
            echo mysql_error();
        }

    }
?>


<form action="" method="post">
<label>Bedrag(in euro):</label>
<input type="number" name="bedrag"><br/>
<label>Voornaam:</label>
<input type="text" name="voornaam"><br/>
<label>Achternaam:</label>
<input type="text" name="achternaam"><br/>
<label>Datum:</label>
<input type="date" name="datum"><br/>
<label>Omschrijving:</label>
<input type="text" name="omschrijving"><br/>
<label>Contant?</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="contant" value="contant"><br/>
<label>Uitgave?</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="uitgave" value="uitgave"><br/>
<input type="submit" name="verzenden" value="Verstuur">
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
<p>Alle velden zijn verplicht.</p>


</body>

</html>
```

Running this on my apache webserver with PHP5 and MySQL installed, gives back a blank page. I was wondering if you guys could help me.

With great thanks in advance,

Comment: You have a syntax error in your PHP code somewhere. put `ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);` at the top of your script to display the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not close your if statement here:

```
if(isset($_POST['verzenden']))
{
```

If you add a `}` where this loop should end (which I am pretty sure is right before `?>`), it should fix that problem.  In addition, you missed a semicolon on this line:

```
$query="insert into inkomsten(bedrag, voornaam, achternaam, contant, datum, omschrijving)
  values('$bedrag', '$voornaam', '$achternaam', '$contant', '$datum', '$omschrijving')"//     }
```

So, just change that line to this:

```
$query="insert into inkomsten(bedrag, voornaam, achternaam, contant, datum, omschrijving)
  values('$bedrag', '$voornaam', '$achternaam', '$contant', '$datum', '$omschrijving')";//     }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm for me. Totally forgot to check if all the loops were closed. Due to some editing of the code, one of the brackets got commented out. Funny how the smallest mistake can create an error you are not prepared for.

Comment: Perfect.  I'm glad it helped.  Just as a small side note, you should also probably look at Mischa's comment so that a blank page will never result. :)

Comment: I have added the code at the top of my script, at the moment just left it commented out but it's there in case I need it ;-)